# Meaning of "there’s a fire burning in someone's bones"

Tags: expressions

What is the meaning of the expression "there’s a fire burning in someone's bones" in below and when does it is said:

> > there’s a fire burning in my bones
> >     And I still believe.

Comment: Sounds like a biblical expression:" if I say, "I will not remember Him Or speak anymore in His name," Then in my heart it becomes like a burning fire shut up in my bones; And I am weary of holding it in, And I cannot endure it."  ◄ Jeremiah 20:9 ► http://biblehub.com/jeremiah/20-9.htm

Comment: A "fire in your belly" is a metaphor for having an intense passion (generally of the non-sexual variety).  Using "bones" is a bit rarer, but is likely used with the same meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from a song called "[Fight Song](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/rachelplatten/fightsong.html)" by Rachel Platten, and it contains several metaphors about depth of feeling.  "Fire" is a common poetic metaphor for intense feeling or passion.  Use the google on search terms "fire, song, lyrics."  English also uses bones to signify depth of feeling -- bone deep, feel it in my bones, cut to the bone.

Lyrics:

Losing friends and I'm chasing sleep

Everybody's worried about me

In too deep

Say I'm in too deep (in too deep)

And it's been two years

I miss my home

***But there's a fire burning in my bones***

And I still believe

Yeah I still believe

Comment: To be clear it's simply a one-off metaphor, written by the writer in question.  It **is not** an idiom or common phrase in English.

Comment: Although "fire in the belly" is.   http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/fire-in-the-or-one's-belly